# Alternative to lightning:overlayLibrary in LightningOut

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-out, lightning-overlaylibrary

I have a `Visualforce` page which loads a `Lightning Aura Component` using `LightningOut`.

The Lightning component uses a `<lightning:overlayLibrary` component, which is not supported in LightningOut.

What alternatives do I have to open a popup in LightningOut?

Comment: have you checked the `lightning:notificationsLibrary` ?